# form of the group of all the root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^{p^m})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is my question (H.W question):

> For natural number $m$ and prime number $p\geq3$ , Let $\zeta_{p^m}$ be primitive $p^m$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
>   Show that the group of roots of unity in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^{p^m})$  have the following form : 
>   { $\pm\zeta^j_{p^m}|0\leq j \lt p^m$ }

I know this is a chyclotomic extentoin and how to compute the minimal polynomial so I tried to prove it by contradiction with Galois theory tools but I got stuck.

I know that { $\pm\zeta^j_{p^m}|0\leq j \lt p^m$ } = $\mathbb{Z}_{2p^m}$ but way this is the only ones ? what about sum of two or three elements from this group ?

thanks

Comment: You mean $\zeta_{p^m}$ as primitive root.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the $\pm\zeta_{p^m}^j$ are roots of unity in the field $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^m})$. If there
was some other roots of unity, say $\zeta_r$, then $r\nmid 2p^m$.
Then $K$ contains the $s$-th roots of unity where $s=\text{lcm}(r,2p^m)>2p^m$.
But the degree of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_s)$ is $\phi(s)>\phi(2p^m)$ as $s=2kp^m$
where $k>1$ is an integer. So $|\Bbb Q(\zeta_s):\Bbb Q|>|K:\Bbb Q|$
so that it's impossible for $\Bbb Q(\zeta_s)\subseteq K$.